# What is the  multiclass loss used in kaggles for measure performance?

Tags: loss-functions, model-evaluation, multi-class

I searched on Internet but cannot find any source about this. What is multiclass loss and what kind of metric is it? If someone can enlighten me, it will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find [this](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/MultiClassLogLoss)?

Comment: difference bet. bad surfer and the master :)